# how to include css/javascript in django 0.96 for appengine project

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I am using django 0.96 for the appengine project. I wanted to use javascript and css in my html files unfortunately i am unable to do it via django...
One solution(which i don't like) is to make my app.yaml something like this:

```
handlers:
- url: /media
  static_dir: static/media
```

But i want it to do with django itself so i avoided using the above line and hence am seeking a "django" way of doing it.
The directory structure of my project is  like(not complete just the relevants
project
  /myapp
  /static
    /media
      /css
      /js
      /images
  settings.py
  app.yaml

and a sample template file header is:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/media/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" rel="Stylesheet" /> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.min.js">$('#date').datepicker();</script>
```

the settings.py has:

```
MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
MEDIA_URL ='/media/'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (

    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myapp/templates'),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static'),
)
```

I know i am making a mistake in the headers or setting because when i use absolute url like:

> then atleast the css works. 
>   The solution exists to do it with app.yaml(as i mentioned above) but i wanted to do it from django itself. Any hints?
>   Thanks

Comment: stackoverflow distorted my directory structure. let me type that again:
1. Project
  i.myapp
  ii. settings.py
  iii. app.yaml
  iv.static
    * media
      ^css
      ^js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about GAE, but I do know Django, and the Django way of doing it is *not* to let Django do it. Your static assets should always be served separately from Django, otherwise you're incurring massive processor overhead for no reason at all.

The way you've got it set up using the `handlers` above looks like the right way.

Comment: http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/static_files/  i found this...Seems you were right. thanks

Comment: +1. Static handlers in App Engine are faster than anything you can implement in user code, too.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for Google App Engine here:

[Static File Handlers](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig.html#Static_File_Handlers)
Outside of django is the best way to serve static files, and GAE automatically handles mime types.